# TypeScript error warning, but it works

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm using angular2-rc1

```
import {RouteParams} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

constructor(
    private _routeParams: RouteParams
){}

ngOnInit() {
  var routeParams = this._routeParams.params

  if(routeParams.code){
    console.log('has code param', routeParams.code);
  }
}
```

In my editor (I'm using atom) it gives me an error for `routeParams.code` and says `Property 'code' does not exist on type {'[key:string]:string; }` everything works fine, even the console log logs out the code param. I can't seem to figure out why this is here or how to get rid of it.

Even more annoying is when I start the server (`npm start`) it gives this error and won't start. I have to comment it out and then the server will start, and then I can uncomment it and it all works fine. Any ideas why this is happening and/or how I can get rid of the typescript error? Let me know any other information to give to help, I'm pretty lost on this.

Comment: What's the error when you hover over the red line? Can you try `var routeParams:any = this._routeParams.params;`

Comment: :any worked! I had tried JSON and string, but neither of those worked.

Comment: when I hover over, it says `any` (before I add the :any)

Comment: oh crap, my past failed I meant to paste that and not the cloudup pic...

Comment: it's updated now, that's why i through it was looking for JSON or string, but i guess it just needed any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a type error. Since `routeParams` variable doesn't have a type, typescript is having trouble with its `.code` property.

You can create an interface for your object: `this._routeParams.params`.

```
var routeParams: customObjectDTO = this._routeParams.params;
```

or you can:

```
var routeParams: any = this._routeParams.params;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help (I'm new to typescript, as I'm sure you can tell ;) )

Comment: @awwester No problem sir, we've all been there :-)